# How to make complete offline installer of python project

Tags: python, installation, lxml, offline

I want to write complete offline installer of my python project with this `requirements.txt`:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
Flask==0.11.1
lxml==3.7.0
peewee==2.8.5
pymongo==3.4.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.12.3
tqdm==4.10.0
wget==3.2
```

What is the best way to do this:

1. Download all packages from requirement with follow command (**should I do this on production platform: Ubuntu 14.04?**):

   pip install --download ext_packages -r requirements.txt --no-binary :all:
2. And then install:

   pip install --no-index --find-links="ext_packages" -r requirements.txt

but `lxml` not going to be installed by `pip`, unless the following command is executed (by [documentation](http://lxml.de/installation.html)):

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

So, my question is: what is the best way to distribute my project on computer **without Internet** on Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Comment: Have you considered downloading the packages into your project file and run `pip.install(packagelocation)` for each package?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with lxml can be solved by changing beautifulsoup4 parser (see [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)):

From:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

To:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

And now do not need to install external dependencies:

```
libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```